# Variable passing in javascript is not coming in vue.js tags

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have defined a variable with the name `tn` which has number `10`. I am trying to pass `tn` (which has `10`) in the `v-on:click="add(tn)"` but it does not work. Is it something I am missing.

```
<script>
    var tn = 10;
</script>
<div id="vue-app">
    <p>My age is {{age}}</p>
    <button v-on:click="add(1)"> Add a Year</button>
    <button v-on:click="subtract(1)"> Subtract a Year</button>
    <button v-on:click="add(tn)"> Add a Year</button>
    <button v-on:click="subtract(tn)"> Subtract a Year</button>
</div>

<script>
    new Vue({
        el: '#vue-app',
        data: {
            age: 25
        },
        methods: {
            add: function (inc) {
                this.age += inc;
            },
            subtract: function (dec) {
                this.age -= dec;
            }
        }
    })
</script>
```

Comment: I am not a Vue expert, but your tn variable seems to be outside of your Vue app.
Could that be the issue?

Comment: @ISAE it does'nt matter even if its outside. That's a javascript variable and ideally I should access it. But for no reason I am unable to do so.

Comment: @fear_matrix it does matter. the vue template compiler will use a `with(this) {}` block around your template (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54055807/8411406)). so if you write `tn` in your template, it will be interpreted as `this.tn`, same with `window`, which will become `this.window`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Vue template, the components or instance properties are accessible. When engine translate the template then the var `tn` you declared is not accessible.

Hence, you can add the `tn` var to the instance property like

```
data: {
  tn: 10,
  // ....
}
```

Alternatively you can use `mixin` to access global var in any Vue instance

**Vue Mixing:**

```
Vue.mixin({
   data: function() {
     return {
       get tn() {
          return 10;
       }
     }
  }
})
```

**Now use in Vue Instance:**

```
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    created: function() {
        console.log(this.tn)
    }
});
```

And in template now `tn` might be accessible.

**Working demo:**

```js
Vue.mixin({
    data: function() {
        return {
            get tn() {
                return 10;
            }
        }
    }
})

new Vue({
    el: '#vue-app',
    data: {
        age: 25
    },
    methods: {
        add: function (inc) {
            this.age += inc;
        },
        subtract: function (dec) {
            this.age -= dec;
        }
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.1.3/vue.js"></script>
<div id="vue-app">
    <p>My age is {{age}}</p>
    <button v-on:click="add(1)"> Add a Year</button>
    <button v-on:click="subtract(1)"> Subtract a Year</button>
    <button v-on:click="add(tn)"> Add a Year</button>
    <button v-on:click="subtract(tn)"> Subtract a Year</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Glad to help you :)

Answer (score 1):

You can't [access global variables](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54055807/8411406) in vue templates, only variables defined on the vue component directly.
You need to either move `tn` into the components data, or use a computed property.

Example moving `tn` into `data`:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#vue-app',
  data: {
    age: 25,
    tn: 10
  },
  methods: {
    add: function(inc) {
      this.age += inc;
    },
    subtract: function(dec) {
      this.age -= dec;
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="vue-app">
  <p>My age is {{age}}</p>
  <button v-on:click="add(1)"> Add a Year</button>
  <button v-on:click="subtract(1)"> Subtract a Year</button>
  <button v-on:click="add(tn)"> Add a Year</button>
  <button v-on:click="subtract(tn)"> Subtract a Year</button>
</div>
```

or with a computed property:

```js
const tn = 10;

new Vue({
  el: '#vue-app',
  data: {
    age: 25
  },
  computed: {
    tn() {
      return tn;
    }
  },
  methods: {
    add: function(inc) {
      this.age += inc;
    },
    subtract: function(dec) {
      this.age -= dec;
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="vue-app">
  <p>My age is {{age}}</p>
  <button v-on:click="add(1)"> Add a Year</button>
  <button v-on:click="subtract(1)"> Subtract a Year</button>
  <button v-on:click="add(tn)"> Add a Year</button>
  <button v-on:click="subtract(tn)"> Subtract a Year</button>
</div>
```

Please note though that your component will **not** update when you change the global `tn` variable with this computed property.

If you want to change `tn` dynamically and want the component to update automatically, you can take a look at [vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/).

Edit:
If you need access to a global variable from multiple components, you could also assign it on the `Vue.prototype`:

```js
const tn = 10;
Vue.prototype.$tn = tn;

new Vue({
  el: '#vue-app',
  data: {
    age: 25
  },
  methods: {
    add: function(inc) {
      this.age += inc;
    },
    subtract: function(dec) {
      this.age -= dec;
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="vue-app">
  <p>My age is {{age}}</p>
  <button v-on:click="add(1)"> Add a Year</button>
  <button v-on:click="subtract(1)"> Subtract a Year</button>
  <button v-on:click="add($tn)"> Add a Year</button>
  <button v-on:click="subtract($tn)"> Subtract a Year</button>
</div>
```

Comment: my code logic is a bit different. I know that we can handle the variable in this manner which you have mentioned but I need to handle something which is a separate javascript snippet in which I have defined the variable as I did above. In a nutshell I have a separate javascript code in which I have to pass the variable in v-on:click.

Comment: @fear_matrix the computed property should work in that case. (except if you want to dynamically change it, which will not work)